# If-statement boolean logic not working within my switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error, do-while, user-experience

I am writing a function for a personal project and am trying to create a function that will center lines of text onto the console. I found a solution for Strings less than a line long, but am encountering difficulties with larger Strings. Code is behaving erratically and I think the logic is not working correctly due to some issue unknown to me. I don't have a ton of experience with switch statements but figured it was a good time to learn through doing. So if the answer is obvious don't be mad.

To explain the code I input a String words that I want to split into 2 smaller Strings that are centered on a 200 (fullscreen) character wide console(might upscale later to allow more lines). My idea is to have three preferences on where to split the line: periods, commas and finally spaces. I am trying to use a do-while loop to attempt each preference in order and find an acceptable splitting spot between 175 and 200 character. All of my issues on inside the splitWords(String words) function but I included the function that calls it for holisticness.

This is the written code:

```
public static void printCenter(String words){ //assumes a 200 character wide console

        int x = words.length();
        int y = (200-x);
        int z= y/2;

        if(x<175){ //no need for formatting second line
            for(int i=z; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
                System.out.print(words);
            for(int i=z; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        if(x>=175){
            String[] split = splitWords(words);
            String words1 = split[0];
            String words2 = split[1];

            int x1 = words1.length();
            int x2 = words2.length();
            int y1 = (200-x1);
            int y2 = (200-x2);
            int z1= y1/2;
            int z2= y2/2;

            System.out.println("Split at: " + x1 + "\t Output below");
            System.out.println("");

            for(int i=z1; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
                System.out.print(words1);
            for(int i=z1; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int i=z2; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
                System.out.print(words2);
            for(int i=z2; i>0; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
public static String[] splitWords(String words){
    String line1 = "";
    String line2 = "";
    int splithere = 0;
    //strings used to create new substrings
    String firstpref = ". ";
    String secondpref = ", ";
    String lastpref = " ";
    int tries = 0;
    boolean set = false;
    System.out.println("started");
    do{
        switch(tries){
            case 0:
                int num = words.indexOf(firstpref,175);
                if(num<200){
                    System.out.print("this should be less than 200: " + num);
                    splithere = words.indexOf(firstpref,175);
                    set=true;
                    System.out.println("found valid split during pass: " + tries + " at: " + splithere);
                }
            case 1:
                if(words.indexOf(secondpref,175)<200){
                    splithere = words.indexOf(firstpref,175);
                    set=true;
                    System.out.println("found valid split during pass: " + tries + " at: " + splithere);
                }
            case 2:
                if(words.indexOf(lastpref,175)<200){
                    splithere = words.indexOf(firstpref,175);
                    set=true;
                    System.out.println("found valid split during pass: " + tries + " at: " + splithere);
                }
        }
        tries++;
    }while(set = false);

    line1 = words.substring(0,splithere);
    line2 = words.substring(splithere,words.length());
    String[] output = {line1,line2};
    System.out.println(" ended with boolean = " + set);
    return output;
    }
```

Here is a sample output from a 347 character string:

> started
> found valid split during pass: 0 at: 235
> ended with boolean = false
> Split at: 235    Output below:

> You are at a junction in the middle of town. To the west, through a guard post, lies the heart of the village, protected and highly guarded this area is home to politicians, great scribes and hunters and most importantly, cheif's perch (String splits here). The older dirt road running North ends in a T with a decorated stone road running East.

You can see from my code that I have tried to insert messages to help me diagnose the problem. It seems to me like the If statement inside the switch is running some of it's code even when the If statement is off. How else can you explain the console printing out the "found valid split during pass 0 at: 235" when that String should never have a number greater than 200 as defined by the boolean logic in the If statement.

Another vexxing issue is that the do-while loop ends while set=false. You can see this in the output text on the console. I cannot see why it doesn't increment tries++ and run the loop again with a new switch statement.

Comment: You need to place `break` after each `case`, otherwise it will fall through and execute the other cases. This is a frequent mistake, esp. as some languages have other conventions where they will implicitly `break` (IMO the saner behavior).

Comment: `} while (set = false);` is an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: thanks you! You two were spot on and now it looks great. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not a solution as such, but there is a series on the “Marco Codes” YouTube channel where Marco builds a text editor in Java. It’s quite interesting

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote the switch, it 'falls through'. Here's a simple snippet to show how fall-through works:

```
int x = 5;
switch (x) {
case 5: System.out.print("5");
case 4: System.out.print("4");
case 3: System.out.print("3");
case 2: System.out.print("2");
case 1: System.out.print("1");
}
```

The above would print `54321`. Not just `5`.

You need breaks at the end of *every* case statement:

```
int x = 5;
switch (x) {
case 5: System.out.print("5"); break;
case 4: System.out.print("4"); break;
case 3: System.out.print("3"); break;
case 2: System.out.print("2"); break;
case 1: System.out.print("1"); break;
}
```

Now it would print just `5`. Many java linting tools, including IDEs, can be configured to require that `break` (they will mark your code as problematic if you fail to write one at the end of every case block but the last), or possibly a comment with the word 'fallthrough' in it someplace, to indicate you *want* the fallthrough behaviour.

However, there are better options; other forms of switch that don't suffer from this conundrum. In fact, these days (JDK17+) switch is rather flexible. With arrow-notation, case blocks no longer fall through:

```
int x = 5;
switch (x) {
case 5 -> System.out.print("5");
case 4 -> System.out.print("4");
case 3 -> System.out.print("3");
case 2 -> System.out.print("2");
case 1 -> System.out.print("1");
}
```

Now it prints simply `5`.

You can also write switches as expressions:

```
int x = 5;
String wordified = switch(x) {
  case 5 -> "Five";
  case 4 -> "Four";
  case 3,2,1 -> "Low";
  default -> "Who knows";
};

System.out.println(wordified);
```

prints `Five`. In this mode, your cases have to 'exhaustive' (cover every value the input type could possibly have. Which, for `int`, would require about 4 billion entries, obviously not feasible. But with a `default` block it's now exhaustive. Non-exhaustive switches used as expressions give you a compiler error that tell you that your switch isn't exhaustive.

NB: If you're thinking: Say, that fallthrough thing, that's pretty stupid! Yeah, probably. Java v1.0 bent over backwards to look, syntactically, as close to C as possible, given that C was absolutely dominant at the time in the kinds of environments java wanted to be popular in. This explains a ton of 'what were they thinking' syntax choices (and C, itself, has similarly 'rooted in the mists of history' explanations for *their* choices, and so on, until you're Indiana Jones spelunking through the 1950s to figure out why things turned out the way they are. Fun hobby, though). Don't knock it - it worked. Java was more popular than C within about a decade of its release, and still is.

Comment: I always figured the fall through thing was in part to aid in keeping the compiler simpler/smaller. One less rule and a switch block behaves like any other block of code. Fall through can be useful but it can lead to errors so it’s use should be documented. For “crazy” use of a switch in C check out “Duff’s Device”